# Transfering properties from one object to another with similar definition

Tags: c#

There must be an easier way...

```
    void TransferFrom(object obj) {
        foreach(PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            prop.SetValue(this, obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
    }
```

I have two separate libraries with the same object definition - all property names/types are the same. Is the above the only way to copy the values or is there another way? I'm unable to reference one of the dlls and the object to be copied is passed as an object rather than a distinct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over both assemblies, take a look at [Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx), which were designed specifically to do what you're describing.

Comment: I'm currently testing this out and I hope to have a response soon. Thanks.

Comment: The data contracts concept is quite powerful; it's the data content equivalent to interfaces.  It's not too difficult to get up and running once you have the basics down.  The class you'll want to read up on is DataContractSerializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Comment: One quirk worth noting is that the serializer will not call your object's constructor; this threw me for a loop the first time I used it.

Comment: Perfect, seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Dan Bryant.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is flexible and powerful. I'm not sure if it'll work without referencing both types, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Thanks, I found that link through another question similar to mine but at this point I'm looking for a code only solution. But will consider it if it leads to that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if classes in both assemblies have the same type name, you can try to use XmlSerializer by serializing instance of type from assemlby A then deserialize instance of type from assembly B from the same stream.